# dijkstra with adjacency list and minimum heap as queue vs adjacency matrix and a normal array as "queue"

Tags: dijkstra, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

Which one should be faster? I have written a script comparing both run time, initially the implementation with adjacency list and minimum heap performs faster, but as the number of nodes/edges increases, it seems the latter perform faster Is this result expected?

With 500 nodes, my script says the latter perform faster by almost 30ms

Comment: It sounds quite counter-intuitive. Heap should be the right data structure with Dikstra or A* or the likes.

Comment: But adjacency list traversal also affects the time, no?